# Create UIActionSheet 'otherButtons' by passing in array, not varlist

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I have an array of strings that I want to use for button titles on a UIActionSheet. Unfortunately, the otherButtonTitles: argument in the method invocation takes a variable length list of strings, not an array.

So how I can I pass these titles into the UIActionSheet? The workaround I've seen suggested is to pass nil into otherButtonTitles:, then specify the button titles individually by using addButtonWithTitle:. But this has the problem of moving the "Cancel" button to the first position on the UIActionSheet rather than the last; I want it to be the last one.

Is there a way to 1) pass an array in lieu of a variable list of strings, or alternatively 2) move the cancel button to the bottom of the UIActionSheet?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure if this will work but the cancelButtonIndex property of UIActionSheet is not read-only. Try setting it and see if that changes the order of the buttons?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

I got this to work (you just need to, be ok with a regular button, and just add it after :

```
NSArray *array = @[@"1st Button",@"2nd Button",@"3rd Button",@"4th Button"];

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title Here"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // ObjC Fast Enumeration
    for (NSString *title in array) {
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
    }

    actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: This works; thanks. Didn't realize that the cancelButtonIndex property could be set. One thing I think we can all agree on: Apple's API for this sucks.

Comment: I second this! And 99,99% of their documentation also sucks. It is like trying to learn brain surgery from a book written in archaic hebrew without knowing that language.

Comment: I very much wish I could up vote this many many more times. Cracking answer and I cannot believe I've gone this long not knowing about this!

Comment: What about if we want the cancel button to be red like usual?

Comment: @JimThio `cancelButton` is not red. The `destructiveButton` is red.

Comment: Sadly, this solution suffers from a bug in UIActionSheet that `[UIActionSheet addButtonWithTitle]` does not seem to correctly set `firstOtherButtonIndex` (which should be used in the delegate's `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` rather than hardcoding 0 or similar stuff). Getting nasty with converting an `NSArray` to `va_list` doesn't sound like a great solution either. :-( This API is so damn ugly.

Comment: I used this recently showing the action sheet from a bar button item, and it seems to have a bug because the last item is not being shown. I had to add an empty button title to workaround this. I'm not sure if this is only on iOS 7

Comment: To solve the problems with the indexes, i created a `NSDictionary` containing the titles as keys with `NSNumber` (e.g. `@(0)`) as values. In `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` for example i get the title for the specific pressed `buttonIndex` via `buttonTitleAtIndex` on the `actionSheet`. Then i get the value with the title as key from my dictionary and take the `integerValue` of this value to do a `switch-case`. For me this is working great. Don't forget to add the all button titles also cancel etc. to your dictionary

Answer (score 78):

One little note: [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:] returns the index of that button, so to be safe and "clean" you can do this:

```
actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
```

Comment: Will that turn the cancel button red?

Comment: @JimThio No, red button is called "destructiveButton", and there's a respective property `destructiveButtonIndex` for it

Answer (score 3):

Taking Jaba's and Nick's answers and extending them a little further.  To incorporate a destruction button into this solution:

```
// Create action sheet
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
// Action Buttons
for (NSString *actionName in actionNames){
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle: actionName];
}

// Destruction Button
if (destructiveName.length > 0){
    [actionSheet setDestructiveButtonIndex:[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle: destructiveName]];
}

// Cancel Button
[actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex: [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"]];

// Present Action Sheet
[actionSheet showInView: self.view];
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the swift version for the response :

```
//array with button titles
private var values = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"]

//create action sheet
let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: nil, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: nil, destructiveButtonTitle: nil)
//for each value in array
for value in values{
    //add a button
    actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle(value as String)
}
//display action sheet
actionSheet.showInView(self.view)
```

To get value selected, add delegate to your ViewController :

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIActionSheetDelegate
```

And implement the method "clickedButtonAtIndex"

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    let selectedValue : String = values[buttonIndex]
}
```

Comment: For future users... It worked... but it is deprecated... use https://stackoverflow.com/a/41322537/884674