# iphone - initializing a UIActionSheet with an array of buttons

Tags: iphone

I am initializing a UIActionSheet and I would like to populate its "otherButtonTitles" from an Array, Set, or whatever, like this

```
UIActionSheet* aSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:"hi There" 
delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:nil
destructiveButtonTitle:nil
otherButtonTitles:[mySetOfStringsOrWhatever allObjects], nil];
```

is that possible?

(I have tried this but Xcode doesn't like it)

thanks in advance.

Comment: what does xcode say about it?

Comment: it complains it is expecting a NSString, not an array or set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create UIActionSheet 'otherButtons' by passing in array, not varlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384044/create-uiactionsheet-otherbuttons-by-passing-in-array-not-varlist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so, but you can pass `nil` then iterate through your array/set/whatever and call `addButtonWithTitle`

See [Create UIActionSheet otherButtons by passing in array not varlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384044/create-uiactionsheet-otherbuttons-by-passing-in-array-not-varlist)